# Help to understand these quantifiers' effects on each other

Tags: logic, model-theory

In my assignment, I have the following question:
Find a model with the domain {a, b, c, d} so that:

```
M |= ∀x∃yT(x, y),
M |= ¬∃x∀yT(x, y),
M |= ¬∃y∀xT(x, y),
```

and T^M is a transitive relation.

What I struggle to understand is how the different quantifiers and variables affect eachother.
I believe the first rule states that for ALL x, there is an Y.
However, THERE ISN'T an X for every Y, and there isn't an Y for every X.

Doesn't the first contradict with the two latter?

Comment: It means once you choose an $x$, you can find a $y$. But there isn't any $x$ for which you can choose any $y$ you want.

Comment: 1st one: Correct. for ALL x, there is an Y such that...

Comment: @CaptainLama I struggle a bit still to comprehend. The way I interpreted your answer was that I can choose an X and get a Y, but in a sense, the Y that I get from the X I choose, is inherently random? Or, did you just explain how it contradicts itself?

Comment: 2nd one: it is not true that there is an X such that for ALL Y... It is equivalent to: for ALL x, there is an Y such that **not**...

Comment: There is no contradiction. You can get an example by looking at $\mathbb{R}$ with the order relation (which is not an answer to your exercise though since it's infinite): for any number $x$, there is a number $y$ which is bigger. But you cannot find a number $x$ such that all numbers $y$ are bigger than $x$.

Comment: The two do not contradict each other: consider the Integers: for each  X there is an Y that is greater than and for each X there is an Y that is **not** greater than...

Comment: The word in English is "quantifier", not "quantor".

Comment: @all thank you for all the answers, it helped me come to a hopefully correct set for the transitive relation T^M, where every X is related to at least one Y, but never related to ALL Y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have understood the first.
The second says you can't have all of $(a,a), (a,b), (a,c), (a,d)$ and similar sets.
The third says you can't have all of $(a,a), (b,a), (c,a), (d,a)$ and similar sets.
Once you insist that $T$ be an equivalence relation these are redundant.